# How to create new window linked to previous? - python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, window

I am creating very simply building game. I want to click on button in tkinter, which open a new window. In this window you would choose type of building, which you use in previous window, so both windows should be linked in this way. Do you now ho to simply create this type of window? Thank you.

Comment: use parent as argument for subwindow and then you will have access to parent window inside subwindow. There is no need anything special.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a million ways of doing it, this may not be the smart one but i hope this does what you are looking for, but if you looking to make games with python you should probably check out the pygame module or the panda3d.

```
from tkinter import *
class app():

        def __init__(self):
            self.choosen_building=None
            self.root=Tk()
            Button(self.root,text='Choose buildig',command=lambda:self.type_of_building(self.root)).pack()
            self.root.mainloop()

        def type_of_building(self,main_window):
            self.new_win=Toplevel(main_window)
            self.new_win.geometry('500x500')
            Label(self.new_win,text='choose the kind of building you want').pack()
            Button(self.new_win,text='buildin a',command=lambda:self.set_choosen_building('Building A')).pack()
            Button(self.new_win,text='building b',command=lambda:self.set_choosen_building('Building B')).pack()
            self.new_win.mainloop()

        def set_choosen_building(self,new_value):
            self.choosen_building=new_value
            Label(self.root,text='choosen_building:'+str(self.choosen_building)).pack()
            self.new_win.destroy()

app()
```

and when you ask questions in this site you should show what you have worked on and state the problems you faced, do that next time.